# Preorder Traversal

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science, trees

For Each Preorder Traversal, we have multiple Inorder Traversal. this is True or False Conclusion? every one would help me and add some detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes because from a single preorder sequence you can create multiple trees.

This is of course true in general case, BSTs have a unique inorder sequence.

for example preorder: acdef

```
      a
     / \
    c   d
   / \
  e   f
```

has lot's of inorder.